# Customizing projects widget in a dashboard of sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

In the default dashboard that the sonar provides, the user can view all the projects that have been linked with the sonar server. But as an admin I want to limit that projects list based on the user's access to the projects. For example, If I'm the user and I have got access to three or four projects on sonarqube, then I should be able to see on those projects. Customised dashboards was an option but I want to do it as an admin. Could anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

First let me clarify "access". The permissioning scheme in SonarQube allows you to control whether a user can

- Administer - twiddle settings on a project
- Administer Issues - edit severity, status, ... of project issues
- See Source Code - (this one should be self-explanatory)
- Browse - know that the project exists at all in the instance

If a user doesn't have Browse permission on a project, then it will never show up in the interface for her.

So all you have to do is control your users' browse permissions. SonarQube will take care of the rest automatically.

Comment: Thank you Ann. I could get what was desired.

Comment: Then perhaps you'd like to [accept] the answer @MahenderSingh? :-)